# How to identify a windows installation folder?

Tags: windows, installation, uninstall, windows-10-preview

I'm working on a pc that sometimes randomly boots up windows 10. It has 2 SSD's and 5 HDD's. BCDedit doesn't show the windows installation.

How can I find where this windows 10 installation is installed? I need to remove it, not just roll it back. There is already a fresh install on this computer.

Does the windows 10 folder maybe have certain files that I can search for in order to look for the installation folder?

Comment: The next time it boots up, create a file, then look for that file.

Comment: When your PC booted into the Windows 10 installation you should be able to locate the files. Open Disk Management and find the partition with a status of `Healthy (System...`

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm working on a pc that sometimes randomly boots up windows 10. It has 2 SSD's and 5 HDD's. BCDedit doesn't show the windows installation.
```

1. Windows 7/8/10 boot sequence is not random.
2. Boot Configuration Data (BCD) contains all the parameters and settings for booting any Vista, Windows 7/8/10.
3. You can list full contents of BCD with:

   **bcdedit /enum ALL /v >c:\bcdedit.txt**

and the result will be stored in the file bcdedit.txt in c:\.
You can use any text editor to examine this file. Every Windows loader has a name (description) and a drive letter (device) specifying where its target is.

If you cannot find out yourself the answer where Windows 10 is installed, post bcdedit.txt and a picture of disk management for further help.

Answer (score -1):

**To boot from the Windows you want to:** right click on my computer, or computer, select properties, advanced system settings, under startup and recovery, click settings, at the top uncheck display list of operating systems, and make sure the one you want is selected under the drop box.

**To delete the boot entry for Windows 10:**
Step 1.
To launch msconfig:
a. Click Start.
b. In the Search text box, type msconfig
c. Launch msconfig by selecting it from the search results above the search text box.

Step 2.
After msconfig is launched:
a. Go to the Boot tab
b. Select the boot entry you want to delete.
c. Click the Delete button and then click OK.
Note: Make sure to be logged in to the Windows partition you want to keep when performing these steps so you don't delete the good installation by mistake.

**To delete data from Windows 10 installation:** 
1. Open Disk Manager by typing diskmgmt.msc on Start and hitting enter.
2. Right click on the drive/partition to which you installed Windows 10. It’s recommended to check the drive letter once again via the Windows Explorer.
3. Delete Volume Disk Manager >  Disk Management > Choose Delete volume.
Alternatively, you can also choose to only Format or individually delete the Windows 10 directories via the Windows Explorer.
Create a new partition over the free space that is generated and you’re good to go.

Comment: According to the author there isn't a boot entry for Windows 10.

Comment: Edited my post. It's impossible that the computer recognizes an installation of Windows 10 and attempts to boot it if it doesn't exist on the HDD or MSconfig boot entry.

Comment: I don't disagree with that fact.  But that is wha the author is telling us.  So we either have to through **comments** determine what actually is happening then submit an answer or submit an answer that helps them ideintify which partition Windows 10 exists on.  Your last update STILL isn't that helpful since the author does not know which partition Windows 10 exists on.

Comment: BCDEdit and "Boot" tab in msconfig is two different places. He wrote he looked in BCDEdit (which is a command-line tool) but didn't mention in his question that he looked in msconfig as I suggested.